# Laravel eloquent query: create scope to check for column with values intersecting with static list of values?

Tags: php, json, laravel, intersection

I have a static list of valid values, e.g. `$valid = ['one','two']`,
and a column (e.g. `types`) in my model with multiple values (casts to array).

I could check if they intersect: `array_intersect($model->types, $valid)`

Can I create a `scope` that includes only the models that intersect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can with the `orWhereJsonContains` function, something like that:

```
public function scopeNameIt(Builder $query,$array): void //pass the array as a parameter to the scope
 {
   $query->where(function($query) use ($array)){
      foreach($array as $element){
         $query->orWhereJsonContains('types',element);
      }
   }
 }
```

You can read about it in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#json-where-clauses)

Accorded to the documentation you can pass the array as well to the `whereJsonContains` function

```
public function scopeNameIt(Builder $query,$array): void //pass the array as a parameter to the scope
 {
   $query->WhereJsonContains('types',$array);
 }
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Will use the first one. The second one (pass an array `->whereJsonContains('types', $valid)`) means `types` must contain *all* of the `$valid` types (and I want: *any*).